# why can an object be initialized in this way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, ingredients):
        self.ingredients = ingredients

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Pizza({self.ingredients!r})'
```

why can this `Pizza(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes'])` work? Normally i will do like this `Pizza1 = Pizza(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes'])`

in this situation:

```
class Pizza():
    pass
```

what if i input two `Pizza()`? are the two `Pizza()` a new object? i have tried this in my Vscode, but it returns the same ID address.

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings
And thanks, this is a good question, TIL.

Comment: Again, not sure if this is what you are asking, but whenever you use `Pizza()` a new `Pizza` object is created

Comment: I don’t understand your question either, and it may be too broad for Stack Overflow. I would recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general.

Answer (score 3):

`Pizza(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes'])` is an expression, just like `1+1` or `f(1, 2, 3)` or `"dogs"`. At runtime, this expression evaluates to a new instance of `Pizza`, different from any other instance in the program. You can therefore write things like:

```
def printPizza(pizza):
  print("Here's a pizza")
  print(repr(pizza))

printPizza(Pizza(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes']))
```

When you have a statement (not an expression!) like `pizza = Pizza(['mozzarella', 'tomatoes'])`, what happens at runtime is that the result of evaluating the `Pizza(...)` expression (i.e. the new instance of `Pizza`) is assigned to the `pizza` variable. Of course, then you can easily run `printPizza(pizza)`.

If the `Pizza()` expression is run twice, each time it returns an instance of `Pizza` that's distinct from any other instance currently alive in the program. However, if the instance returned from the earlier `Pizza()` call is no longer alive, then the new call to `Pizza()` may have the same id as the earlier instance (that's no longer available).

For example, in IDLE:

```
>>> id(Pizza())
65959272
>>> id(Pizza())
65959272
```

Because the instance returned from the first call to `Pizza()` is no longer stored anywhere when the second call to `Pizza()` executes, the id can safely be reused. (There are never two pizzas alive at the same time with the same id.)

But if you do something like this:

```
def printIds(pizza1, pizza2):
  print(id(pizza1))
  print(id(pizza2))

printIds(Pizza(), Pizza())
```

You'll see that two unique IDs are printed. This is because both pizza instances are alive at the time when the ids are printed (one is stored in `pizza1` and the other in `pizza2`) so each must have a unique ID.